# List Array in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the structure in ts:

```
pacientes: Array<{ paciente: MpPacienteModel  }>;

   resp.json().forEach(element => {
   let agenda: MpPacienteModel = new MpPacienteModel(element);
   this.pacientes.push({ paciente: agenda });
});
```

In HTML i try recived:

```
     <ion-item *ngFor="let menu of pacientes" (click)="btnSalvarPaciente()">
         <div *ngIf="menu.codmppaciente>=0"> {{menu.codmppaciente}} {{menu.nome}} </div>
         <div *ngIf="menu.codmppaciente == null"> {{menu}}</div>
  </ion-item>
```

The information going for HTML in this format:
[image]

But my in my HTML print: `[Object Object]`

How do I make the treatment for the HTML receive and display the value of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

HTML displays the Value. It's an Object
`{{menu}}` in Template points to `new MpPacienteModel(element)` in .ts. That's an object. For example you can add a `toString()` function to `MpPacienteModel` and call this function in Template.